# css not working in Mozilla and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I tried with everything like proper style tags and all. but still site is not working in Firefox and IE
Link: http://webkurn.com/chrysler/index.html
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: For any one to help you need to tell what you have tried. Simply posting the website URL will not help other to understand your problem and the effort you have made.

Comment: Thanks @sagar. I went through so many articles. 1.)I tried to remove space in media query.  2.) I checked each element that all are compitable in IE and mozila. code working fine in chrome and opera but not working in IE and mozaila.

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your code?

Comment: @sagar fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/jksheth/mqdngmbk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your CSS Statements they apply only on webkit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.). If you are pointing to a specific browser then you have to use `webkit`. Here you are making your queries to run on specific browser chrome or safari.

Try removing the webkit `-webkit-min-device-pixel` and check. Hope this help you

Comment: thanks a lot. ;) Solved it by removing -webkit-min-device-pixel but one more question that I have what can be used instead of -webkit-min-device-pixel to run in IE and Mozila.

Comment: You have to use Webkit as property. can you mark this as answered if this solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the problem is with the cache only if all the stylesheet tags are perfectly written. First try to remove your cache from your browsers of your website.Also, there are great tools like firebug(firefox) and inspect element tools(almost all browsers) which can be used to check the stylesheet file if it is updated or not.